# monitoring a control in c# other than using threads

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

i have a winform application in which i have a lot of controls that needs continuos monitoring. For example there is a button and it should be enabled only when two other buttons are disabled, and they disable at separate instances. So what i am doing now is using a thread to monitor the two other buttons in a continuos while loop such as

```
while(true)
{    
if(btn.enabled==false and btn1.enabled==false)
{
bt3.enabled==true
}
}
```

though it does what i need it seems wrong to me. Also its very expensive considering the number of threads i have to spawn to manage my controls, there are certain controls that needs to check five or six different things to before it can do an action and threading seems the only way possible to me.

Please tell me if there is any other way to do this

Comment: How about using a timer? It will resolve your thread issues but I still think it would be better just to set the bt3.enabled value whenever you make the change, or use properties to set btn and btn1. enabled properties and in those properties evalaute and set bt3.enabled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is that inefficient, it is incorrect; you should never access a control's properties except from the UI thread, due to thread affinity. *Setting* properties (the enabled assignment) is especially bad, but reading them (the enabled check) is bad enough.

Rather than continuous monitoring, those forms should update *themselves*, based on event notifications. For example, by hooking [`EnabledChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabledchanged.aspx) on the two buttons.

```
// (in the form initialization code)
btn.EnabledChanged += UpdateButtons;
btn1.EnabledChanged += UpdateButtons;

//...
private void UpdateButtons(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     bt3.Enabled = !btn.Enabled && !btn1.Enabled;
}
```

you could also (instead) do this at the code that causes the `Enabled` property to change.

Comment: great thanks, im doing a lot of this inefficient methods in my apps. For instance in all my multithreaded apps i find myself accessing the UI elements from another thread. However i have taken care of cross thread calls by using a delegate and using invokerequired. BUt reading your answer i feel like even that shouldnt be done. What is the best option to do when we need to make cross thread calls to UI elements.

Comment: @swordfish well, there's only 2 to choose from really, Invoke and BeginInvoke - and they mostly do the same thing...